# Configuring Cloudflare DNS for Office 365 to Maintain Separate Mailboxes on sitground.com

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cloudflare, mailbox, office365

I have a web application on the site **siteground.com**, associated with the domain **adward.com.** I used **microsoft365.com** as the mail service. On **siteground.com**, there is a mailbox, for example (*job.adward.com, info@adward.com*), that I do not want to add to **microsoft365.com**. I have configured all of this through **cloudflare.com**.

The issue is that after adding **microsoft365.com** DNS records to **cloudflare.com**, emails such as *info@adward.com and job.adward.com* won't be properly handled. Is it possible to configure **microsoft365.com** DNS records on **cloudflare.com** so that emails sent during this time will be delivered to **siteground.com** (*job.adward.com, info@adward.com*), while the rest will go to **microsoft365.com**?

at least suggest me other options for using these mailboxes!

I wrote a microsoft.com DNS record (NS, MX, TXT, SPF) on Cloudflaer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manage this at the DNS level; DNS only knows about *domains*, not actual email addresses.

When you configure the MX record for a given domain to point to a given email service, *all* emails addressed to *all* recipients (including non-existent addresses) in that SMTP domain will be delivered to that provider.

If you want to only handle *some* addresses on a provider and send the rest of the messages to a different provider, you'll have to handle this at the SMTP level.

There are solutions for that, but they differ between email servers (or service providers); the only constant is, SMTP namespace sharing is not for the faint of heart: you should know very well the ins and outs of what you are trying to do and how to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

[image]You can use domain connect which automatically set the right dns records for Microsoft 365
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-at-cloudflare?view=o365-worldwide

Edit:
You can't do this on dns server level. You could use a postfix send only MTA, where you forward everything for siteground.com to the mailserver responsible for that domain and Microsoft365.com to mailserver for Microsoft365.com. Or maybe the cloudflare email routing service is an option

Comment: This *might* be part of the solution, but it sure won't achieve SMTP domain sharing on its own.

Comment: I will update my post